# Хранение разновидностей товара (интернет-магазин)

Tags: sql, база-данных, интернет-магазин

У товара могут быть разновидности. Например, размер. То есть товар один и тот же. Но при помещении товара в корзину нужно различить товары по размеру - притом, что цена у разных размеров тоже разная.

Как лучше отразить это в базе: каждый размер считать отдельным товаром - или прикрутить к товару опции? В первом случае страницы будут завалены разновидностями одного товара (ну и избыточность базы). Во втором - труднее фиксировать, какой именно товар заказан, и совсем трудно организовать учёт остатков.

Жду мнений. Спасибо!

Comment: В первом случае избыточность легко устраняется группировкой схожих товаров, во втором случае проблема с остатками легко устраняется приписыванием остатка к этим самым опциям

Comment: На одном из интернет-магазинов, строение которого мне доводилось изучать, проблему решали делением товаров на product и subproduct — product содержит всю основную информацию товаре с описанием и картинками, а subproduct'ы связаны со своим основным product и содержат более конкретную информацию вроде размера, цены и остатка

Comment: == устраняется группировкой схожих товаров== - но это же фактически добавление подкатегорий. Или нет?

Comment: Деление на размеры это неизбежно подкатегории в том или ином виде, вопрос лишь сводится к тому, как этими подкатегориями удобно управлять

Comment: тут надо смотреть, артикул меняется али нет? Вообще логика конфигурационного товара, товара с опциями, изменяя их не меняется sku но добавляется цена и меняется размер, может быть несколько зависимых опций как размер и цвет, одного цвета столько то размеров, у другого столько то. В заключение, объективно сказать как реализовать сложно, необходимо смотреть на существующую архитектуру.